# TemplateDoesNotExist at /poll/poll/result.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I get this error TemplateDoesNotExist at /poll/poll/result.html....I think I'm pointing to poll/poll/result.html but how do I point it to poll/result.html

```
{'Gender': <QuerySet [{'Gender': 'female', 'Diseases': 'Malaria', 'Number': 1}, {'Gender': 'female', 'Diseases': 'cholera', 'Number': 2}
```

I am new to django but what possibly am I doing wrong here.This is the file structure for template.html: mysite/polls/templates/polls/template.html and for result.html its mysite/polls/templates/polls/result.html

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from . models import MyModel
from . forms import MyModelForm
from django.db.models import Count
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class CreateMyModelView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'poll/template.html'
    success_url = 'poll/result.html'


class MyModelListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.values('Gender', 'Diseases').annotate(Number=Count("Gender"))
        return render('poll/result.html', {'Gender': queryset})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^$', views.CreateMyModelView.as_view(), name='abc'),
                path('poll/result.html', views.MyModelListView.as_view(), name='result'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

Gender = (
    ('male', 'MALE'),
    ('female', 'FEMALE'),
)

Diseases = (
    ('cholera', 'CHOLERA'),
    ('hiv', 'HIV'),
    ('Malaria', 'MALARIA'),
    ('Typhoid', 'TYPHOID'),
)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Gender, default='MALE')
    Diseases = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Diseases, default='MALARIA')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Gender

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Diseases
```

result.html

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}

<h1></h1>

<ul>
    {% for choice in Gender %}
        <li> {{choice.Gender}} - {{choice.Diseases}} - {{ choice.Number}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


<a href="{% url 'poll:template' question.id %}">Vote Again?</a>\\

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template is at "poll**s**/result.html" but you told the view it was "poll/result.html".

(Note, you really shouldn't give your URLs paths ending in "html"; it's not necessary, and it's confusing you. URLs and template locations have nothing to do with each other.)

Comment: how do I make it point to poll/result.html instead of polls/result.html

Comment: Change the line:     template_name = 'poll/template.html'